# Python List into a Dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, input

I have a program that reads in two (or three) whitespace delimited tokens, 2 strings, and optionally, a number, per line

My program:

```
import sys
d = sys.stdin.readlines()
d = [i.split() for i in d]
print(*d)
```

Running the program:

```
python3 program12.py
Austin Houston 300
SanFrancisco     Albany         1000
NewYorkCity    SanDiego
['Austin', 'Houston', '300'] ['SanFrancisco', 'Albany', '1000'] ['NewYorkCity', 'SanDiego']
```

But now I need to add these items into a dict, which is where I get confused:
    For the example input, the dict would need to look like this:

```
{'Austin': {'Houston': 300}, 'SanFrancisco':  {'Albany': 1000}, 'NewYorkCity': { 'SanDiego': True }}
```

Dicts are still confusing to me on how they even work, let alone filling one up with what seems like a nested dict. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### update

One line better solution.

`d = {e[0] : {e[1] : e[2] if len(e) == 3 else True} for e in d}`

---

### update

I ignored that your last element's length is just two, so if you could build the list like this `[['Austin', 'Houston', '300'],['SanFrancisco', 'Albany', '1000'],['NewYorkCity', 'SanDiego', True]]`, then the solution below could work.

---

One line solution.

`d = {e[0] : {e[1] : e[2]} for e in d}`

Comment: Wow I can't believe it's that easy! How can I build my list to add True whenever there is no number?

Comment: @Coder117 New better solution: `d = {e[0] : {e[1] : e[2] if len(e) == 3 else True} for e in d}`

Comment: Amazing! Bless your soul.

Answer (score 2):

```
d = { e[0]: {e[1]: (e[2] if e[2:] else True)} for e in d}
```

Add this one line at the end.